# log to specific console with console.log

Tags: javascript, console.log

How do you determine from any location in express which connection the logic initiated from?

I am using Express, and doing a lot of logic in my code. To let the user know what is happening, I use console log pretty much everywhere. That way if the logic is being run by command line it just prints to the console, and if the logic runs through the express url route I override the console like this:

```
console.log = (print) => {
    res.write(print + '<br>')
};
```

Pretty simple, but when two run at the same time the newest one steals the console log function so it starts to print the console logs from both processes. Any suggestion as to how this should run Without passing a special print function to all of my functions as a parameter?

Maybe use a global print object that detects which node process it started in and only print statements that come from that source, but then how would you close a connection?

Comment: You can't update a global property like `console.log` and expect only a local application. How do you control the scope where your change applies?

Comment: That is what i am wondering. Any thing is possible programming, just have to figure it out. 

I was thinking maybe add a random variable as an attribute to the process variable, and pass that into the console log to control the scope?

Answer (score 0):

Use npm module winston https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston

```
var winston = require('winston');

  winston.log('info', 'Hello distributed log files!');
  winston.info('Hello again distributed logs');

  winston.level = 'debug';
  winston.log('debug', 'Now my debug messages are written to console!');
```

And provide some transport https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md

Comment: maybe that combined with: winston-express-middleware might work